# pyYAML, expected NodeEvent, but got DocumentEndEvent

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I'm trying to dump a custom object, that is a kind of a list of objects. So I overrode the `to_yaml` method of the `YAMLOBject` class from which I set my class to inherit from:

```
@classmethod
def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
    """ This methods defines how to save this class to a yml
    file """

    passage_list = []

    for passage in data:
        passage_dict = {
            'satellite': passage.satellite.name,
            'ground_station': passage.ground_station.name,
            'aos': passage.aos,
            'los': passage.los,
            'tca': passage.tca,

        }
        passage_list.append(passage_dict)

    passage_list_dict = {
        'passages': passage_list
    }

    return dumper.represent(passage_list_dict)
```

When I call the `yaml.dump` method, the output file is created correctly with the correct data:

```
if save_to_file:
    with open(save_to_file, 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(all_passages, f, default_flow_style=False)
```

but at the end of the execution I get a `EmitterError: expected NodeEvent, but got DocumentEndEvent()`

I believe it's related to not closing correctly the YAML document because when I was debugging my code I was getting `save_to_file` files that were missing the new line at the end of the document. Could it be? Or is it something else?

Comment: If I use `dumper.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, passage_list_dict)` it works (but it adds the tag at the top of the file that I would like to avoid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because `dumper.represent` doesn't return anything. You want to use `dumper.represent_data` instead.